# C++: Reading from a txt file line by line and word by word with uneven amount of words each line

Tags: c++

Good evening,

I have a txt file which contains information about some cars.
According to it's type each car has it's own properties, for example:

Type **1** car has name, buying price, renting price.

Type **2** car has name and buying price.

Type **3** car has name and buying price.

Type **4** car has name, buying price, renting price and insurance price.

```
Type(Int)  Name(String)         Buy(Int)     Rent(Int)   Insurance(Int) 
1          toyota               5000         100   
3          mazda                6000         130
2          mitsubishi           10000   
1          honda                5000         110
4          ferrari              20000        220         1000
```

For now all I want is to read the file and print each car's type so I i know that my code works.
What I've tried so far is this:

```
ifstream carsFile(cars.txt);

string carType;
string carName;
string carBuyPrice;
string carRentPrice;
string carInsPrice;
string line;

while (getline(carsFile, line))
{
    istringstream buffer(line);

    while (buffer >> carType >> carName >> carBuyPrice >> carRentPrice >> carInsPrice)
    {
         if (carType == "1")
         {
            cout << "Car type 1" << endl;
         }
         else if (carType == "2")
         {
            cout << "Car type 2" << endl;
         }
         else if (carType == "3")
         {
            cout << "Car type 3" << endl;
         }
         else
         {
         cout << "Car type 4" << endl;
         }
    }
}

carsFile.close();
```

The code above only works for type 2 and 3(which have the same properties), how can I read every type even if the line has uneven number of words?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your second `while` requires *all* reads to work, otherwise it returns false. You will have to split that up into several inputs, and check each one for success/fail individually.

Comment: Can  you elaborate a bit more? How exactly can I split that into several inputs?

Comment: Search the internet for "StackOverflow c++ read file struct space separated".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do `buffer >> carType >> carName >> carBuyPrice >> carRentPrice >> carInsPrice`, you're attempting to read all of that information without checking if they exist or not, causing the input to fail and the body of the loop not getting executed. Why do you need a while loop in the first place?

You should input the type of the car first, then have something like some if statements or a switch statement to decide what to do for each type of car.

```
while(getline(carsFile, line))
{
    istringstream buffer(line);
    int type, rent, insurance;
    string name;
    buffer >> type >> name;
    switch(type)
    {
    case 1:
        buffer >> rent;
        //...
    case 2:
        //...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend modeling a structure to the record in the file.  Next, overload `operator>>` to read the fields.
Example:

```
struct Car_Info
{
  int type;
  std::string manufacturer;
  int buy_price;
  int rent_price;
  int insurance_price;
// Here's the kicker
  friend std::istream&  operator>>(std::istream& input, Car_Info& ci);
};

std::istream&  operator>>(std::istream& input, Car_Info& ci)
{
  std::string text_line;
  std::getline(input, text_line);
  if (input)
  {
    std::istringstream text_stream(text_line);
    // Initialize optional fields
    ci.rent_price = 0;
    ci.insurance_price = 0;
    text_stream >> ci.type
        >> ci.manufacturer
        >> ci.buy_price;
        >> ci.rent_price
        >> ci.insurance_price;
    }
}
```

Your input loop will look like:

```
std::vector<Car_Info> database;
Car_Info car;
while (input_file >> car)
{
   database.push_back(car);
}
```

The structure is used instead of parallel arrays to reduce defects caused by synchronization errors.

A string is used to read one record of text.  Any reading issue (such as eof) will change the status of the input stream, thus a stringstream is used to isolate the errors generated by missing fields.

Answer (score 1):

The condition of your inner while loop is the state of your stream (converted to a boolean expression) after *all* formatted input operations have been performed. If *any single one of them* fails, the stream will be flagged as erroneous, causing the condition to evaluate to `false`.

**You need to check the input operations separately.**

[Live example](https://ideone.com/FEaAVg) for demonstration purposes:

```
while(std::getline(std::cin, line)) {
  std::cout
    << "have \"" << line << "\"\n"
    << "read together:\n";
  read_together(line);
  std::cout << "read separately:\n";
  read_separately(line);
}
```

with

```
void read_separately(std::string const & line) {
  std::istringstream buffer(line);
  int a;
  int b;
  if (! (buffer >> a)) std::cout << "- a failed" << std::endl;
  if (! (buffer >> b)) std::cout << "- b failed" << std::endl;
}
```

vs

```
void read_together(std::string const & line) {
  std::istringstream buffer(line);
  int a;
  int b;
  if (! (buffer >> a >> b)) std::cout << "- a or b failed" << std::endl;
}
```